# Show specific Quick Action for specific file extension

Tags: applescript, automator

I am newbie with Applescript and Automator. I am trying to build a Quick Actions which will be able to propose different functions according to the type of file for example. 
If the file is test.sh quick action will be a and b 
If the file is document.pdf action will be c and d

I succeed in creating my actions but not to make them specific to file type. I don't know where to start as I don't see any possibility to make input conditional like if input = .sh do a and b.

Any help on how to proceed will be really appreciated.

Thank you, [image]

Comment: Generally speaking, quick actions are supposed to be type-specific; rather than making 1 quick action to do different things for five file types, you would make 5 quick actions to do 1 thing for each file type. If you really want 'one action to rule them all', you'll need to have it accept all file types and then sort them in code using file sort actions or AppleScript. Is that really what you want?

Comment: I don't necessarily need an action to rule them all, but i need that the action specific to PDF don't show when i click on an excel file for example. Can i make that happened ?

Comment: Yes, that's possible. I'll give an answer with the details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick Actions are meant to be type-specific, so in general the best practice is to write one Quick Action for each file type. These quick actions will only appear in the Finder when files of that type are selected.

In many cases you can specify the file type when you create or edit the Quick Action in Automator. For instance, to create a Quick Action that appears only when PDF files are selected, set the pulldown menus at the top of the workflow to say "Workflow receives current *PDF files* in *Finder*":

[image: Automator workflow header]

then complete and save the Quick Action.

If you want more fine-tuned control over what types of files the Quick Action 'sees', you can edit its info.plist file and change its file types. After you've saved the Quick Action, navigate to ~/Library/Services in the Finder (that's the Services folder in the Library folder of your Home folder). Find the package with the name of the Quick Action (e.g., "Open in Preview"), control-click on it to get the contextual menu, choose Show Package Contents, and then open the Contents folder. You'll see the following:

[image]

Open that info.plist file in a plain-text text editor — I prefer BBEdit, but TextEdit will work fine if you make sure 'rich text' is turned off — and look for the `NSSendFileTypes` key. It will look something like the following:

```
    <key>NSSendFileTypes</key>
    <array>
        <string>com.adobe.pdf</string>
    </array>
```

`com.adobe.pdf` is a Uniform Type Identifier (UTI), and you can add or substitute in any system-recognized UTI. Here is the list of [system-declared UTIs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/UTIRef/Articles/System-DeclaredUniformTypeIdentifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009259-SW1), but applications can declare their own UTIs and register them with the system, so this list is not necessarily exhaustive. For instance, if you want your Quick Action to send both PDFs and image files to Preview, you would search on the system-declared UTIs page and find that the base UTI for images is `public.image`, and then edit the info.plist to read:

```
    <key>NSSendFileTypes</key>
    <array>
        <string>com.adobe.pdf</string>
        <string>public.image</string>
    </array>
```

Save this, and the Quick Action will now appear whenever you selected PDFs *or* images. Note that if you manually edit the info.plist file it might get overwritten if you edit and save the Quick Action in Automator.

Only the first two relevant Quick Actions will appear in the Finder window; any extras will be collapsed under the `more` button. To change the ordering so that the Quick Actions you use most are up first, open System Preferences, click the Extensions item, open the Finder section, and drag the items in the right-hand list into the order you prefer.

Comment: That was the right thing to do in my case ! Thanks for the explanation

Comment: Thank you for this great answer! The bit about editing the plist and changing the UTI was exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 2):

After looking at the image of your **QuickAction**, it is not at all useful for anything other then a selected **PDF** *document* in **Finder**.

The first *action* should be a **Set Value of Variable** *action* so its *contents* can be retrieved multiple times using **Get Value of Variable** with however many **Filter Finder Items** *actions* needed to process the different *file types*, followed by the appropriate *actions* for each *file type*.

You would also use **Ignore this action's input** *checkbox* under **Options** for this *action*  to detach it from the previous set of *actions*.

The image below shows a rough outline example of what I'm referring to:

[image]